# Segmentation fault when deleting a templated array

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

-------I forgot to add some stuff so this is a small section for clarity-------

1. I added a hastebin with the full code
2. This is a school assignment
3. The only std::class im allowed to use is std::string. No other external c++ libraries allowed (c is allowed though for some reason)
4. If you do end up reading the code, stringList is supposed to be the strings on a instrument and not a actual string

---

I want to make a templated function that quickly reallocated an array that gets passed to it, regardless of type, to a new size. I have this code currently:

```
template<class t>
t* tool_reallocateArray(t array[],int &oldSize,int newSize){
    t* helper = array;
    array = new t[newSize];
    if(array!=0){
        int toCopy=0;

        if(oldSize>newSize){
            toCopy = newSize;
            //cout<<"new is smaller";
        }else toCopy = oldSize;

        for(int i=0;i<toCopy;i++){
            //helper[i];
            array[i] = helper[i];
        }
        delete[] helper; //this is where the problem is
    }
    oldSize = newSize;

    return array;
}
```

This code works if I don't delete the helper variable, however, if I don't the old memory still exists in the program, which I have verified with memory.

If I, however, leave this line in, I get a segmentation fault error from my debugger and this error in memory.

```
    Error #2: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS: reading 0x0778fdf8-0x0778fdfc 4 byte(s)
# 0 std::__cxx11::basic_string<>::~basic_string               [../../../../../src/gcc-5.1.0/libgcc/libgcc2.c:1169]
# 1 tool_reallocateArray<>                                    [C:/Users/MoustacheSpy/Documents/Programmierung/schulprogramme/Instruments/Instrument.h:67]
# 2 Instrument::setNumberOfMajor                              [C:/Users/MoustacheSpy/Documents/Programmierung/schulprogramme/Instruments/Instrument.cpp:49]
# 3 Instrument::Instrument                                    [C:/Users/MoustacheSpy/Documents/Programmierung/schulprogramme/Instruments/Instrument.cpp:95]
# 4 StringedInstrument::StringedInstrument                    [C:/Users/MoustacheSpy/Documents/Programmierung/schulprogramme/Instruments/StringedInstrument.cpp:61]
# 5 main                                                      [C:/Users/MoustacheSpy/Documents/Programmierung/schulprogramme/Instruments/main.cpp:11]
Note: @0:00:00.562 in thread 9584
Note: instruction: mov    (%ecx) -> %eax
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. The only way I can get this to work is by leaving out the delete.

----HERE IS MY FULL PROGRAM CODE IF ANYONE IS INTERESTED. FEEL FREE TO PUT SOME CONSTRUCTIVE CRITISIM BUT REMEMBER THE LIMITATIONS I HAVE, WHICH I POSTED IN THE VERY TOP OF THE POST----
 https://hastebin.com/giyucukeya.cpp

Comment: Why are you trying to `delete[]` an array that is neither owned nor created inside the function? You don't know how it was created (e.g.: if it was `new[]`ed). You only ever `delete[]` what you created with `new[]`

Comment: 1) use a `std::vector` instead of a c-style array 2) realize that you dont need to write such a function

Comment: On a second read `helper` is **not** a new array, it is a variable referring to the same array as the passed in `array`, it cannot cause a memory leak on its own

Comment: The problem is elsewhere. Most likely a naughty write outside the bounds of the array you're about to delete. We need to see an sscce.

Comment: And where did `basic_string` get involved here?

Comment: 1. Don't post links to code, try to create a [mcve] instead 2. Please explain how the arrays you are passing to your constructor are "dynamically allocated" - I don't see the keyword `new[]` there

Comment: This is how the constructor works: 1. Array gets set to 0 (in a class and is just a pointer to some type) 2. The reallocation function gets called (the one I posted) 3. If the thing is 0 all that happens is that the array gets allocated and a pointer gets returned 4. Back in the constructor the pointer gets set to whatever is returned. Also the full code is everything that could be relevant since it might also be a problem with inheritance (which this example includes). I can make a smaller example in a sec

Comment: I read that hastebin code - the arrays you are passing to your constructor are **NOT** created using `new[]` -> trying to `delete[]` any of them invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: @UnholySheep The arrays im passing to the constructor are not the ones that get passed to the templated function. The things that get passed to said function are from the class being constructed, which are just pointers, which then get allocated by the templated function (in case they are null) or reallocated (in case they arent null, which is the case when the user uses the set function in main)

Comment: @MoustacheSpy UnholySheep is 100% right. But I see you don't understand, so let me try to tell the same thing in other words: the pointer passed to `delete[]` has to point to a memory location obtained by a call to `new[]`. Otherwise it is undefined behavior. This is not your case, as the pointer you pass points to an automatic storage duration array, e.g. `stringListBass`. Thus you have Undefined Behavior and your program crashes.

Comment: and for this question to be answerable you need to create a [mcve]. The question is off-topic if you need to visit an external resource in order to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok forget my other answer. I see where you're coming from now.

I just pulled your code and finally got it running. The short answer to your problem is that `majorList` and `stringList` are never being given a default value so to get your code to work i made the following alterations. I gave majorList and stringList a default value of nullptr in the respective constructors as shown below.

Even if you are leaving a variable (pointer or not) empty for later use it is always wise to still give that variable a default value usually using the null and nullptr. Your code is a good example why, Delete has a built-in check for a nullptr however because you never assigned any value to the pointers they were left with random values in them left over from when that chuck of memory was last used so Delete couldn't tell that the pointers were empty and tried to delete a invalid pointer.

majorList:

```
Instrument::Instrument(const Instrument& other)
:name(other.name),majorList(nullptr)
{
    this->setNumberOfMajor(other.numberOfMajor);
    this->setMajorList(other.majorList);
}


Instrument::Instrument(const string& name, int numberOfMajor, string* majorList)
:name(name),numberOfMajor(0),majorList(nullptr)
{
    this->setNumberOfMajor(numberOfMajor);
    this->setMajorList(majorList);
}
```

stringList:

```
StringedInstrument::StringedInstrument(string name, int numberOfMajor, string* majorList, int numberOfStrings, char* stringList)
:Instrument(name,numberOfMajor,majorList),stringList(nullptr)
{

    cout<<"Constructing stringed instrument"<<endl;
    this->setNumberOfStrings(numberOfStrings);
    this->setStringList(stringList);
}

StringedInstrument::StringedInstrument(const StringedInstrument &other)
:Instrument(other.getName(),other.getNumberOfMajor(),other.getMajorList()),stringList(nullptr)
{
    this->setNumberOfStrings(other.numberOfStrings);
    this->setStringList(other.stringList);
}
```